# Compact submanifold of $S^n \times R^m$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, product-space

On exercise 6 of chapter 11 of "Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" by Spivak, one is asked to apply the exact sequence for the pair $(S^n \times R^m,\{p\}\times R^m)$ to calculate $H_c^k(S^n \times R^m)$. This is simple, but one thing is bothering me: the hypothesis of the theorem that assures the existence of such exact sequence for the pair $(M,N)$ requires that $N$ be a **compact** submanifold of $M$, and I can't see why $\{p\}\times R^m$ is a **compact** submanifold of $S^n \times R^m$.

The answer can be a bit stupid, but I've tried some ideas and got stuck. Any hints would be great.

Comment: You're right. This is a crazy error. But I believe that Spivak cuts corners and only needs a closed (embedded) submanifold. This is what you need to get a tubular neighborhood.

Comment: Yeah, was wondering that too. Thanks!